Supabase join query for multiple foreign keys with js
I'm using Supabase and basically I need the equivalent of this SQL statement using supabase JS client.
SELECT * from ratings
JOIN users ON ratings.user_id = users.id
JOIN cafes ON ratings.cafe_id = cafes.id
WHERE cafe_id = 70 AND user_id = 'a8d15462xxxxxx'

Extended Info:
I have 3 tables:
users (id - primary key)
cafes (id - primary key)
ratings (id - primary key; user_id - foreign key users; cafe_id: foreign key cafes).
Tried many things, most common error was "Could not embed because more than one relationship was found for 'ratings' and 'cafe_id'",
for example when trying
const {data, error} = await supabase
    .from('ratings')
    .select(
      `
        *,
        cafes: cafe_id("*"),
        users: user_id("*")
      `
    )

Using supabase sql editor I can get the intended result but unfortunately I'm unable to figure out how to get the same result with the supabase api. Could anyone help? Many thanks in advance!
